# Turn a Mysql Subquery in a Join

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I turn this subquery in a `JOIN`?

I read that subqueries are slower than `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT 
    reklamation.id, 
    reklamation.titel,
    ( 
        SELECT reklamation_status.status 
        FROM reklamation_status 
        WHERE reklamation_status.id_reklamation = reklamation.id 
        ORDER BY reklamation_status.id DESC 
        LIMIT 1 
    ) as status
FROM reklamation 
WHERE reklamation.aktiv=1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT r.id, r.titel, MAX(s.id) as status
FROM reklamation r
LEFT JOIN reklamation_status s ON s.id_reklamation = r.id
WHERE r.aktiv = 1   
GROUP BY r.id, r.titel
```

The key point here is to use *aggregation* to manage the cardinality between `reklamation` and `reklamation_status`. In your original code, the inline subquery uses `ORDER BY reklamation_status.id DESC LIMIT 1` to return the highest `id` in `reklamation_status` that corresponds to the current `reklamation`. Without aggregation, we would probably get multiple records in the resultset for each `reklamation` (one for each  corresponding `reklamation_status`).

Another thing  is to consider is the type of the `JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` would filter out records of `reklamation`s that do not have a `reklamation_status`: the original query with the inline subquery does not behave like that, so I chose `LEFT JOIN`. If you can guarantee that every `reklamation` has at least one child in `reklamation_status`, you can safely switch back to `INNER JOIN` (which might perform more efficiently).

---

PS:

> I read that subqueries are slower than `JOIN`s.

This is not a universal truth. It depends on many factors and cannot be told without seeing your exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

Using `JOIN` query can be rewritten to:

```
SELECT reklamation.id, reklamation.titel, reklamation_status.status
FROM reklamation 
JOIN reklamation_status ON reklamation_status.id_reklamation = reklamation.id
WHERE reklamation.aktiv=1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you read is incorrect.  Subqueries can be slower, faster, or the same as joins.  I would write the query as:

```
SELECT r.id, r.titel,
       (SELECT rs.status 
        FROM reklamation_status rs
        WHERE rs.id_reklamation = r.id 
        ORDER BY rs.id DESC 
        LIMIT 1 
       ) as status
FROM reklamation  r
WHERE r.aktiv = 1;
```

For performance, you want an index on `reklamation_status(id_reklamation, id, status)`.

By the way, this is a case where the subquery is probably the fastest method for expressing this query.  If you attempt a `JOIN`, then you need some sort of aggregation to get the most recent status.  That can be expensive.